# Проблема со структурой в VS 2010

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, инициализация

Объявляю структуру

```
struct list //двусвязный список целочисленный
{
    int val;
    list* prev = NULL;
    list* next = NULL;
};
```

Выводит такие ошибки:

*error C2864: list::prev: в пределах класса могут быть инициализированы только статические константные данные-члены целого типа*

*error C2864: list::next: в пределах класса могут быть инициализированы только статические константные данные-члены целого типа*

Не могу присвоить NULL, подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Инициализация должна быть либо через `{}`, либо а конструкторе

Comment: @ヒミコ Почему же? Можно и через `=`, но только не в таком древнем компиляторе... - https://ideone.com/zBWa6V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не помню уж, поддерживает ли VC++2010 вообще С++11 и поздние, так что скорее всего, только в конструкторе...

```
struct list //двусвязный список целочисленный
{
    list(int v = 0):val(v),prev(0),next(0){};
    int val;
    list* prev;
    list* next;
};
```